# Setup TFS plugin in Jenkins to access TFS server

Tags: ssl, jenkins, tfs, ssl-certificate, firewall

This is just to share my problem and solution to everyone.

I setup the plugin with the instructions from 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin

1. First problem:
   FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Connection refused
   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Connection refused
2. Second problem:
   FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Answer (score 1):

First problem:
FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Connection refused
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Connection refused

This is due to the firewall between my Linux Jenkins server and the Windows TFS server. I had Network team open the port 8080 and 443 from the Jenkins server to the TFS server. 
That fixed the first problem.

2. Second problem:
   FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

This is due to my incorrect URL to the TFS DefaultCollection
I used the https for "Server URL". This will demande a SSL certificate to be install on the Jenkins linux server.
https://swcosvctfs01.wco.int:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/

After switching to http as below, the error went away, and Jenkins was able to checkout a copy of the TFS sourcecodes successfully.
http://swcosvctfs01.wco.int:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/